# Flutter - `serialPort.open()` Cause Exception: `Last Error is 0`

Tags: flutter, dart, arduino, serial-port

I write a code that send a string data from Flutter Windows Application to Arduino Nano using the library `serial_port_win32`.

Here is the relevant Flutter Dart Code:

```
void sendData() {
  final List<String> listPorts = SerialPort.getAvailablePorts();

  if(listPorts.contains("COM5")) {
    final serialPort = SerialPort("COM5", openNow: false, BaudRate: 9600);
    serialPort.open();

    if(serialPort.isOpened) {
      serialPort.writeBytesFromString("HELLO");
      serialPort.close();
    }
  }
}

void main() {

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    sendData();
  });

  runApp(const MainApp());
}
```

And here is the relevant Arduino C code:

```
#include "logic/logic.h"
#define LED1 4

void setup() {
  pinMode(LED1, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    String msg = Serial.readString();
    string2Morse(LED1, msg.c_str());
  }
}
```

I connected my Arduino Nano device into the computer using a USB port and the Serial Port `COM5` is available in the Arduino. I tried to send the string `"HELLO"` to the Arduino using the Serial Port `COM5` and translate the message to Morse-Code through a LED.

The calling to the function `serialPortopen()` resulted with this exception:

```
Exception: Last error is 0
```

It's strange because in Win32, if `GetLastError()` returns 0 that indicates that the procedure has succeeded. I researched on Google and ChatGPT and I didn't get any answer that I'm satisfied with.

Thanks for any clue or information that will help me solve the problem.

Comment: I'm currently facing the same issue, any luck solving this error? @YFSoftwareDevelopment